# How to use native platform icons for ToolBarItems in Xamarin.Forms (programmatically)?

Tags: android-actionbar, icons, uinavigationbar, toolbar, xamarin.forms

**What I have:**

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` app with a `ToolBar` (`ActionBar` on Android, `Navigation Bar` on iOS). Within the `ToolBar` I have a `ToolBarItem` to delete something.

**What I want:**

For the `ToolBarItem` mentioned above I want to use the native platform icons (f.e. a trash can).

**My question:**

What is the proper way to achieve this? It seems that the only way to do this is to add and load separate png-files as described [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Icons_and_splashscreens). For Android this is not such a big deal I can officially download the icon files from Google's developer page. For iOS this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this looks to be almost impossible to override. Looking at the source for `ToolbarRenderer` you can see the `UpdateItems` method. This assumes that all of the toolbar items are of type `ToolbarItem` and it does not invoke a custom renderer for them, instead calling through directly to an extension method that converts `ToolbarItem` values into `UIBarButtonItem`s containing a `UIImage`.