# Can I use standard icons from Windows Phone in a ToolbarItem?

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms page with a toolbar item like this:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="Cancel">
  <ToolbarItem.Icon>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" WinPhone="button_cancel.png" />
  </ToolbarItem.Icon>
</ToolbarItem>
```

This is using a bitmap for showing a cancel icon in Windows Phone. But in Windows Phone there is already predefined icons like this (in the Segoe UI Symbol font). Can I use them instead of bitmaps?

Comment: It seems, that this is currently [not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27387691/426227).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom renderer for a NavigationPage which then replaces normal images sources to the native one while using custom fonts. More here (examples are for Android and iOS but should be easily adopted to Windows too: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17278/custom-font-in-xamarin-forms-font-awesome/p1